# can't get access_token at instagram Basic Display API

Tags: instagram, instagram-api, instagram-graph-api

I want to use instagram Basic Display API.
Because want to embed a post on my website．

ーーーーーーーー

In using the instagram Basic Display API,
Official [instagramBasicDisplayAPI]-> [Start Guide] Step 5 "Replace code to get a newborn" does not work.
()

command

```
curl -X POST https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token client_id=10217016XXXX app_secret=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX grant_type=authorization_code redirect_uri=https://XXXXXXXXXXXXXX code=AQAo6y0E4qD・・・・XXXXXXX
```

output

```
{"error_type": "OAuthException", "code": 400, "error_message": "You must provide a client_id"}
```

ーーーーーーーー

１）what's "client_id"?

２）I can't fix this error anyway, how can I fix it?

３）Is it possible to embed Instagram posts on a website using instagram Basic Display API in the first place?

Comment: The client ID is the app ID - from what I remeber - I hit a dead end with trying to display a feed on a site after the change in API - let me know if you manage to get this working as I would be very interested in the outcome

Comment: curl -X POST https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token -F app_id=10217042XXXXXX -F app_secret=869XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX -F grant_type=authorization_code -F redirect_uri=https://XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX -F code=AQCxeWzYrh8-8T5-7XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

Comment: it's needs「-F」.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same error. My issue was a space after the "="